# Saving texture painted material externally?

Tags: texture-painting

Is there a way to save the texture of a mesh that was painted with the texture painter externally?  I'm trying to create a mountain for use in a game and, admittedly, my texturing skills are garbage unless I can just paint on the model (I'm more of a programmer).  I have a mountain with acceptable textures in Blender, but I need to save the painted texture externally for use in Unity.  Google hasn't turned up anything useful.

Comment: What do you mean by 'texture painter externally'? I can open up gimp with a texture created (and saved) within Blender. When externally edited you need to reload it from menu or Alt-R

Comment: When you paint a mesh with Blender's texture painter, how do you save that painted texture to a file or is it even possible to do so?

Comment: Select it in the UV-Editor save it while you're in Blender, edit externally and reload in Blender.

Comment: So you can't save the texture as defined on the mesh in Blender, huh?  That sucks.  Every time I try to edit a texture in an image editor, it never turns out looking like I want.

Comment: If you unwrap an object, the texture should always be applied to the object in the same way.

Answer (score 6):

Open the texture in the UV image editor. If you have multiple textures beside the one you want to save, click the little PNG icon and select the proper image.

[image]

To save the image, click **Image***> **Save As Image**.
You can also hit <kbd>F3</kbd> while viewing the image.

[image]

You will be asked to give a file location.

Comment: Nothing shows in the UV image editor's preview window.  It's just a black image.  If I try to save that image, it just saves a black image.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Carnivoris Did it work?