# How do I save an edited texture to a file from within Blender?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I imported an .obj file with a texture (from photogrammetry app 3DSOM) which I [show on the web using Three.js](https://daveeveritt.github.io/js3d/). As you can see, I need to edit the texture inside the jar, so I successfully imported the .obj file into Blender and edited the texture's appearance using the brush:

[image]

I know the .blend file doesn't save the texture on re-opening.

I can export the file an an .obj and also understand that the .obj format won't export the texture.

Is there a way from Blender to **export the texture I've modified**?

Comment: Texture is a datablock which references to image file. So as long as image file hasn't changed its location you can open UV editor window in Blender, open datablock with mentioned texture (if not already) and press Save Image (Alt+S).  This generally isn't related to whether texture is from photogrammetry app or not, the process is the same. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23888/1245

Comment: Hi I am having do much trouble with this. I've edited my texture and am trying to send it off but cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Image Editor, press f3 to save the image to a desired location and name (save as) and you can press Shift+S to save the image over that previously saved one. (Save)